# Get the center of the pinch-zoom

Tags: android, android-emulator

How can I get the coordinates of the center of the pinch-zoom action? The same center that appears when we press Ctrl in the Android emulator. In addition, is there a way to change it in the emulator? Because it seems that it's always in the center. My intention is to figure out where exactly the user is zooming-in/out in the app.

Thanks!

Comment: what is your code? are you using any specific gesture detecor?

Comment: I don't have any code or specific gesture detector yet. I was trying to find example code about this but I couldn't find.

Comment: so see how `android.view.ScaleGestureDetector` finds focus x/y point

Comment: And is it possible to change that center in the Android emulator?

Comment: afaik no, its not possible, whats your goal actually? doesnt `ScaleGestureDetector` work?

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, but I was wondering because it means that I need to download the app to the phone to test it. Thanks!